# Bind enum to AspxListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, devexpress

I have following `enum` called `BillTypes`:

```
public enum BillTypes
{
    [EnumProperties("Natural Gas")]
    NaturalGas= 1,

    [EnumProperties("Electric")]
    Electric = 2,

    [EnumProperties("Water")]
    Water = 3
}
```

How can I bind this `enum` to an `AspxListBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to run the following: (please bear with me, if the code does not work, due to I'm not familar to `ASP`)

```
BillTypes b = BillTypes.Electric;

AspxListBox alb = new AspxListBox();
alb.Items.Add(BillTypes.Natural_Gas.ToString().Replace("_", " "));
alb.Items.Add(BillTypes.Electric.ToString().Replace("_", " "));
alb.Items.Add(BillTypes.Water.ToString().Replace("_", " "));

alb.SelectedIndexChanged += (ob, ex) => (IndexChanged());
```

And the method `IndexChanged`:

```
public void IndexChanged()
{
    b = (BillTypes)(alb.SelectedIndex + 1);
    // here you can do whatever you want...
}
```

Note a slightly edited `enum` class:

```
public enum BillTypes
{
    [EnumProperties("Natural Gas")]
    Natural_Gas= 1,

    [EnumProperties("Electric")]
    Electric = 2,

    [EnumProperties("Water")]
    Water = 3
}
```

After this you can handle every code you use, according to the variable `BillTypes` `b`.

Comment: no problem, that's what `SO` is for!! Have a nice day!